# Saving rich text in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm a new to Objective-C and I can't find an answer to my problem.
I've written a simple program using a text field to enter some text, then use:

```
SaveFBCover1 = Cover1.stringValue;
DefaultCover1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[DefaultCover1 setObject:SaveFBCover1 forKey:@"SaveCover1"];
[DefaultCover1 synchronize];
```

to save it. After that, it does this

```
DefaultCover1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
loadFBCover1 = [DefaultCover1 objectForKey:@"SaveCover1"];
FBCoverImageText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadFBCover1];
```

to load it. But what I want is to save and load rich text with colors, fonts and so on.

For some reason, it fails to save or load properly. Can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: What is the type of `Cover1`?

Comment: Look up NSAttributedString.

Comment: Cover1 is NSTextField

Comment: You need to be saving Cover1.text instead

Comment: @danielbeard, the `text` property belongs to `UITextField`, not `NSTextField`.

Comment: @danielbeard Adding to JWWalker's comment, the `[UITextField text]` method returns a `NSString`. If this were an iOS project, the OP would want the `attributedText` method instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SaveFBCover1` is getting an NSString from `Cover1.stringValue`, not an `NSAttributedString`, because the . It looks like your code saves that string properly, and you're probably getting the string back when you load it again, but you won't get attributes because you didn't start with an attributed string, nor did you get the attributes of the text in the text view and save them separately.

You can get an attributed string by using

```
SaveFBCover1 = Cover1.attributedStringValue;
```

However, you're going to have to do a little more work to save and load the string (not much, though). `NSAttributedString` isn't one of the types that you can save directly in `NSUserDefaults`, so you'll need to serialize it into an instance of `NSData` first. You can do that quite easily using an keyed archiver. Read about [Keyed Archives](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/archives.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000946-133256-BAJDGHID) in the *Archives and Serializations Programming Guide*.

Comment: Thanks, but still i can't figure it out right how to use it=( Could you please give an example.

Comment: There's [an example in the docs I linked to](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/creating.html).