# How to use store and use an NSMutableAttributedString in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsuserdefaults, nsattributedstring

I want to create an attributed string, then store it in `NSUserDefaults`, and then access it again and assign the attributed string to `textView.attributedText`. How do I go about this? Thanks in advance.

I don't know a lot of objective c, so I could not refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131373/saving-rich-text-in-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: you would have to save just the string and re-add the effects, u can get the string from attString.string

Comment: I suppose you could use NSKeyedArchiver to store the attributed string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving rich text in NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131373/saving-rich-text-in-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to convert your `NSMutableAttributedString` into `NSData` then you store it in `NSUserDefaults`.

```
    // Convert into NSData
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(distanceMutableAttributedString)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "yourStringIntoData")

    // Convert your NSData to NSMutableAttributedString
    let yourStringInData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("yourStringIntoData") as? NSData
    let newStr = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(yourStringInData!) as? NSMutableAttributedString

   // Assign it to your textView
    textView.attributedText = newStr
```