# Adding NSAttributedString to CloudKit

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, cloudkit, nsmutableattributedstring

I need to add some `NSAttributedString` settings for text to CloudKit container.

In CoreData I'm using Atribute type "Transformable". When I'm trying to add `NSAttributedString` to CloudKit I have a warning message in my console log:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Objects of class NSConcreteMutableAttributedString cannot be set on CKRecord'

Can I transform my `NSAttributedString` to some type which CloudKit accepts and in which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the [documentation for `CKRecord`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecord_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014044), you can only store a limited set of data types. Given the possible types, your best option would be to convert the `NSAttributedString` to `NSData`. This can be done using an `NSKeyedArchiver`. Then when you read the data back from CloudKit, you can convert the `NSData` back to the original `NSAttributedString` using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36940864/1226963 for an answer that shows how to go back and forth between `NSAttributedString` and `NSData`. (actually that answer uses `NSMutableAttributedString`). And of course you would put/get the `NSData` into/from a `CKRecord` instead of `NSUserDefaults`.