# Save & Format String using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

To save a string, I use the following code:

```
defaults.setObject(textViews.text, forKey: "userNameKey")
```

To load a previously saved string, I use this code:

```
if let name = defaults.stringForKey("userNameKey") {
        textViews.text = name
}
```

However, the string does not preserve the formatting `(color)!`. Is it possible to save the string and format it using NSUserDefaults, or do I need to use some other method?

Comment: what is `textViews.text`? Is it a NSString? Or an attributed string? A NSString does not have any color information.

Comment: You are saving a `String` to the user defaults. Only an `NSAttributedString` contains color information. You'll have to find a way to store an `NSAttributedString` in user defaults.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36940275/how-to-use-store-and-use-an-nsmutableattributedstring-in-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Or you can save `NSDictionary` of text and RGB.

Comment: to rmaddy: This method preserves the format, but loses text

Comment: @SashDing No, that method does not lose text. Please update your question with your actual relevant code showing how you save and restore the attributed text of your text view. Be sure your update includes log output showing before and after values. Note: When you wish to reply to someone, please use the `@` symbol before their username.

Comment: Thanks for all the important tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found.
Save the new text for example here

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(textView.attributedText)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "sawedString")

    textView.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Upload saved text when opening

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let myStringData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("sawedString") as? NSData {
    let savedString = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(myStringData) as? NSAttributedString
    textView.attributedText = savedString

    }

}
```

Use the NSAttributedString instead of the NSMutableAttributedString!